# Getting mathematical function as user's input

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

I need to know how transfer string input into executable function. 
For example - user write string 'x*Sin(x**2)' and then programm takes it as function, can calculate a value for given x, can plot derivation of this function etc. I've read that there is module called scitools.stringfunction, but as far as I know this module is not callable in python-3.

Any ideas how to make it?

Comment: Take a look about `eval` built-in function

Comment: You can also read the `scitools.StringFunction` source code to understand how it works : https://github.com/hplgit/scitools/blob/master/lib/scitools/StringFunction.py and then port it to python 3.

Comment: this may help: http://www.sympy.org/

Comment: I had the same problem but thanx to @LoïcG., I simply did the following: f=eval(input("enter the math function name")) everything went well

Comment: Be careful when using eval. It can be [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) ...

Answer (score 5):

### For Python 2.X

```
f = lambda x: input() # the user inputs: x**2 + 1
y = f(3)
print y # outputs: 10
```

### For Python 3.X

```
f = lambda x: eval(input())
y = f(5)
print y
```

*Just make sure to `import` the required mathematical functions. And make sure the user inputs a valid Python **arithmetic** expression.*

Comment: Input string `import os; os.system('rm -rf /')`

Answer (score 5):

using [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/) you could do something like this:

```
from sympy import var
from sympy import sympify

x = var('x')  # the possible variable names must be known beforehand...
user_input = 'x * sin(x**2)'
expr = sympify(user_input)
res = expr.subs(x, 3.14)
print(res)  # -1.322...
```

if you want to turn the user input into a function you can call you could to this:

```
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
f = lambdify(x, expr)
# f(3.14) -> -1.322...
```

sympy can do sybolic calculations (including derivatives); if you want to make plots i strongly suggest [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/).

<del>the advantage of using a math library opposed to `eval` is that you do not need to sanitize the user input (against malicious code).</del>
(deleted this thanks to a comment from [ejm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126362/ejm)).

Comment: This is not true: as of posting, `sympify` is not sanitizing user input and is just passing to `eval` internally. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10805. It has high priority label and last activity on this was January 2020 so we might see some change in this. So in other words, be careful with untrusted input using `sympify` same as you would using `eval`.